# Select all columns with specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has around 200 different boolean columns. These are basically On/Off switches used to blacklist data in another application. This also has multiple rows for different functionalities within said application.

As you can imagine, keeping a good overview over which columns are "turned on" for a specific function is rather tiresome when you have to manually check them against some excel sheet, so I want to make my life easier by only displaying columns that are turned on/set to true.

Something like:

```
select [columns with value '1'] 
from table
where function = 'function1'
```

Where this table:

`+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| function  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| function1 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |
| function2 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+`

returns this:

`+----------+------+-------+-----+
| function  | Col1 | Col3 | Col4 |
+-----------+------+------+------+
| function1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
+-----------+------+------+------+`

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: A query's result columns are defined independent of table data, and the number of result-set columns is fixed.

Comment: You can't do "select column of it has value" you select a **row** if a column in that row has a value.

Comment: You would have to write some kind of exceedingly complex custom API for this,

Comment: Seems like, to me, you might have been better off with a column to denote the setting name, and another for the setting's value.

Comment: That edit doesn't change that what you are after isn't what SQL does. Return all the columns, or unpivot them and return them as rows with just the ones with a value of `1`.

Comment: I know that the edit doesnt change anything, i just provided sample data as requested.

Comment: No one had a thought to do this because it's not what SQL does. SQL datasets are defined; you don't choose whether to return a column or not based on its value, as a column has many values; one for each row.

Answer (score 2):

As is mentioned in the comments, *result columns are defined independent of table data*, but the following approach, which returns the columns names as a single column, is a possible solution:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    [Function] varchar(3),
    Col1 bit,
    Col2 bit,
    Col3 bit,
    Col4 bit,
    Col5 bit
)
INSERT INTO Data ([Function], Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
VALUES ('xyz', 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), ('abc', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''

SELECT @stm = CONCAT(@stm, ',(','''', col.[name], ''', ',  col.[name], ')')
FROM sys.columns col
JOIN sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
JOIN sys.types typ ON col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
WHERE 
    tab.[name] = 'Data' AND 
    sch.[name] = 'dbo' AND 
    col.[name] != 'Function'
ORDER By col.[name]

SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
    'SELECT d.[Function], STRING_AGG(v.ColName, '','') AS [Columns] FROM Data d CROSS APPLY (VALUES ',
    STUFF(@stm, 1, 1, ''),
    ') v(ColName, ColVal) WHERE v.ColVal = 1 GROUP BY d.[Function]'
)

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Result:

```
Function    Columns
abc         Col5
xyz         Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, I hope it helps, it's a little tricky, but gets what you want, at least could it helps to your progress, if you have any doubts send me a message or comment, good luck.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestMr') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TestMr
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TestMrColumns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestMrColumns
CREATE TABLE TestMr(x_function varchar(50),col1 numeric, col2 numeric, col3 numeric)
CREATE TABLE #TestMrColumns(y_function varchar(50),valor varchar(50),columna varchar(50))

--TEST VALUES
INSERT INTO TestMr VALUES('fun1',1,0,1)
INSERT INTO TestMr VALUES('fun2',0,1,0)


DECLARE  @script nvarchar(max)
DECLARE  @cols nvarchar(max)
--We get the columns from our table, this columns have to be of the same data_type or this wont work.
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='TestMr' and DATA_TYPE='numeric' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

--we make that columns rows to save them on a tempTable
set @script='select * from TestMr unpivot(valor for columna in ('+@cols+')) unpiv'
insert into #TestMrColumns exec (@script);

--we get the final columns for our select, here we can apply conditions for the columns that we want, in this case, we get
--the columns that had valor=1 and y_function=fun1/
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(columna) FROM #TestMrColumns where valor=1 and y_function='fun1' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

--final select
set @script='select x_function,'+@cols+' from TestMr where x_function=''fun1'' '
exec(@script)
```